# How to set the ssh key to the user git while installing gitolite on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: git, ssh-keys, ubuntu-10.10, gitolite

I am trying to configure a git server on an Ubuntu Server 10.10 with gitolite and following [the tutorial On Ubuntu for Gitolite](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/gitolite).

I first create a user git with the following command : `sudo adduser git`
I set a password to this user.

Then, I generate a rsa key with the command : `ssh-keygen`, I call it `id_rsa_git`.

After that, I want to associate it to the user git with the following command :

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_git.pub git@localhost
```

The prompt asks me the password for the user git, and after giving it (the good one), I get the following error :

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I cannot go further since I am pretty noob in Linux administration. Can anybody help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try to copy your key:

> cd
>
> sudo cp .ssh/id_rsa_git.pub ~git/.ssh/authorized_keys

If doesn't work, open an other console:

> sudo su - git
>
> cd
>
> mkdir .ssh

You can close this console.

> sudo chown git:git ~git/.ssh/authorized_keys
>
> sudo chmod 600 ~git/.ssh/authorized_keys

And now all will be good (no need of ssh-copy-id)

Comment: Thanks a lot ; this works fine. But I also needed to set the user git to the AllowUsers in the sshd_config.

Answer (score 2):

You should not add git.pub to the authorized_keys file. You do that with gl-setup git.pub. If you add the git.pub key by your self you can have lots of problems. gl-setup does it for you and also adds it to your admin repository.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
- going with the default naming convention (`id_rsa.pub`, not `id_rsa_git.pub`)
- passing the parameter for the public key without the `.pub` extension
```

For instance:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_git git@localhost
```

or

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@localhost
```

(if you have generated the private/public key with the default naming convention).

(Note: make sure you generate those keys as you, not as root ;) )

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I went with the default naming convention and remove the '.pub', but I still had the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The password you have set for the user is not the same as the one you are typing at the prompt for `ssh-copy-id`, try resetting the password on the `git` account.

Alternatively you can copy the `id_rsa_git.pub` file to `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` and set the permissions `chmod 600 ~git/.ssh/authorized_keys; chmod 700 ~git/.ssh; chown git:git ~git/.ssh`, this will all need doing as root (or use `sudo`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am sure to use the good password for the user because I am able to connect to the git account using it. I performed all what you described, and then as I went further in the installation of gitolite, I had the following error : Permission denied (publickey,password).
pubkey access didn't work; please set it up using 'ssh-copy-id' or something

Comment: @obo: So are you seeing this: `$ ssh-copy-id git@localhost
git@localhost's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
git@localhost's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
git@localhost's password: 
Permission denied (publickey,password).
`

Comment: yes I am. This is my first problem ; but I am sure that the password I give is the good one.

Comment: @obo Then my answer still stands, please reset your password for you git user, you get that output when you mistype the password.

Comment: I did it. I cannot set an easier password : "git". But I still get the same error.